# Was the Kastor Lieberung-plot resolved in Enemy Within?

Tags: wfrp-1e

I do not own Empire in Flames, the final book of the Enemy Within-campaign for Warhammer Fantasy Roleplay.

Was the "mistaken identity"-plot begun in the very first supplement ever adequately resolved?

Comment: what a fun adventure

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Not at all. I feel like I should dress this answer up more, but... no. Hogshead Publishing was working on a new ending back when they had the license; alas, nothing ever came of it.

Answer (score 6):

The plot was never resolved, no, but I´m not sure it was ever intended to be, either. I have gm-ed the campaign twice, and not one of the players ever asked for any resolution to that particular subplot, I think we all just viewed it as a convenient hook and not at all the point for any of the adventures. In retrospect, it would have been interesting to see what James Wallis (of Hogshead publishing) would have made of it, if his rewrite had ever been published.

Answer (score 6):

The Kastor Lieberung plot is heavily touched upon in *Empire at War* by Alfred Nuñez Jr. a.k.a. Mad Alfred. *Empire at War* is described by the author as:

> ...designed to replace the old GW publication *The Empire in Flames* as the finale of *The Enemy Within* campaign. Why bother rewriting the finale given that second edition WFRP will be set nearly ten years after most of the events in the original WFRP campaign? The answer is two-fold. First, a significant amount of the Warhammer background has changed since the early 1990s when *EiF* was released, rendering much of the events in that publication obsolete. Second, there is a need among us old folk to have a more plausible transition from the “old” background to the “new.”

If you are planning on running the final installment of *TEW*, you might wish to consider *EAW* as a drop in replacement. Well-written by one considered to be a very influential WFRP steward.

It is available from [Strike to Stun](http://www.strike-to-stun.net/downloads).

Answer (score 1):

I feel the Mistaken Identity subplot is resolved nicely when the players play along and find out Mr. Lieberung was a chaos cutlist, and infiltrate his cult to tear it down.

Which happens in that first installment.